# cant play the most recent audio after downloading to an existing path

Tags: node.js, reactjs, filesystems, electron

I have an electron react app that I play audio files using the javascript audio element. I have something like below. However, even though I can confirm that the audio file in local disk changes after pipe, the audio that plays through application won't be updated for around 30 seconds.

```
playAudio = (path) => {
  this.audio = new Audio()
  this.audio.src = filepath
  this.audio.play()
}

this.playAudio('C:\Users\User\Documents\audio.mp3')

request.post({url: 'http://localhost:8080/requestAudio', body: object}, 
  function(err, response, body) {
    //do stuff
  }         
})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`C:\Users\User\Documents\audio.mp3`)
   .on('finish', () => {
       this.playAudio('C:\Users\User\Documents\audio.mp3')
    }
 )
```

So, I was wondering if there is some sort of caching mechanism due to electron or node, that grabs the same file from cache without checking if file content is different.

I've tried disabling cache on electron chrome debugger network tab which didn't 
work.

Other audio player npm modules also seem to work the same way.

Alternatively, I could just append some kind of number to the file name whenever a new file is piped with the same name and grab the most recent while clearing the old ones.
But I'd rather have unique files for each filename.

Comment: You could quickly test this by appending a query parameter to the URL, like `'http://localhost:8080/requestAudio?t=' + Date.now()`. The client should not cache this..

Comment: thanks, I've tried what you suggested but it didn't seem to make any difference on my case

Comment: If you still require help, please make it a (minimal) reproducible example (i.e. the code needs to work, ideally not assuming a specific platform, URL resources need to be available).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone struggles with a similar problem, I've managed to fix this using npm module [howler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/howler). And calling unload on the audio object every time I need to replay altered audio file.

```
this.audio.unload()
this.audio = new Howl({
   src: filepath
});
```